# Build Error with PaymentGateways

Tags: virtocommerce

I downloaded the last source code, but I cannot build mainly because of this error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2428,5): error MSB6006: "LC.exe" exited with code -1.
```

in the `PaymentGatewaysProject`.

Error List in Visual Studio:

```
Error   1   "LC.exe" exited with code -1.   PaymentGateways
Error   2   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\src\Extensions\Payments\PaymentGateways\bin\Debug\VirtoCommerce.PaymentGateways.dll' could not be found C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\FunctionalTests\CSC  FunctionalTests
Error   3   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\src\Extensions\Payments\PaymentGateways\bin\Debug\VirtoCommerce.PaymentGateways.dll' could not be found C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\src\Presentation\FrontEnd\StoreWebApp\CSC  StoreWebApp
Error   4   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\FunctionalTests\bin\Debug\CommerceFoundation.FunctionalTests.dll' could not be found  C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FrontEnd.FunctionalTests\CSC  UI.FrontEnd.FunctionalTests
Error   5   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\src\Presentation\FrontEnd\StoreWebApp\bin\VirtoCommerce.Web.dll' could not be found C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FrontEnd.FunctionalTests\CSC  UI.FrontEnd.FunctionalTests
Error   6   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\FunctionalTests\bin\Debug\CommerceFoundation.FunctionalTests.dll' could not be found  C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FunctionalTests.Helpers\CSC   UI.FunctionalTests.Helpers
Error   7   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\FunctionalTests\bin\Debug\CommerceFoundation.FunctionalTests.dll' could not be found  C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FunctionalTests\CSC   UI.FunctionalTests
Error   8   Metadata file 'C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FunctionalTests.Helpers\bin\Debug\UI.FunctionalTests.Helpers.dll' could not be found   C:\Users\Ale\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\virtoCommerce\Tests\UI.FunctionalTests\CSC   UI.FunctionalTests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and googling a little bit I found this simple step that solved the build problem:
Delete the CONTENT of the file: **licenses.licx**

> nsoftware.InPay.Icharge, nsoftware.InPayWeb, Version=6.0.5329.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cdc168f89cffe9cf